# chrome app bluetooth api

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth

I am trying to get the list of bluetooth devices paired with my windows 7 machine. I took the code from here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth

```
var device_names = {};
var updateDeviceName = function(device) {
  device_names[device.address] = device.name;
};
var removeDeviceName = function(device) {
 delete device_names[device.address];
}

// Add listeners to receive newly found devices and updates
// to the previously known devices.
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceAdded.addListener(updateDeviceName);
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceChanged.addListener(updateDeviceName);
chrome.bluetooth.onDeviceRemoved.addListener(removeDeviceName);

// With the listeners in place, get the list of devices found in
// previous discovery sessions, or any currently active ones,
// along with paired devices.
chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    updateDeviceName(devices[i]);
  }
});

// Now begin the discovery process.
chrome.bluetooth.startDiscovery(function() {
// Stop discovery after 30 seconds.
  setTimeout(function() {
  chrome.bluetooth.stopDiscovery(function() {});
  }, 30000);
});
```

In the manifest file i gave bluetooth permission

```
"bluetooth": {
    "uuids": [ "1105", "1106" ]
}
```

But getDevices always return empty list even after startDiscovery is initiated.

I have enabled bluetooth in my mobile and paired it with my windows 7 as well even then its not showing the paired device when getdevice is called.

The chrome app is frameless and running in developer mode.

BTW my windows bluetooth UI shows my mobile device and some other devices as well

I will be grateful if anyone can suggest where i am making a mistake?